# Process Binary data with Java Azure Functions SDK

Tags: java, azure-functions

I Want to use the Java Azure Functions SDK to:

1. Accept a PDF as input
2. Process the PDF(using the pdfbox library).
3. Return a changedPDF.

The end result should read the PDF from a queue and post the processed PDF to another queue.

Are there examples for reading/writing binary data from a Queue using the Java Azure Functions SDK?

For testing, debugging and other use it would be nice to have:

1. A http trigger that accepts the PDF via post. How to do this in Java? 
   It is currently unclear to me how to use HttRequestMessage in a http trigger.

   1.1. Can I use zero or optional arguments with Http Trigger?

   1.2. Parse the arguments myself using the HttpRequestMessage?
2. You can use HttpResponseMessage as return type and set the return code.
   It is not clear on how to set the mime-type of output to application/pdf.

I tried returning valid html as a string as a first try but that was returned and  rendered as plain/text.

The reason for this, with triggers you do not have to setup a queue.

Comment: You are using azure storage queue ,right?

Answer (score 0):

According to your needs, my advice may be divided into several steps below:

***Use [Azure Storage Queue Java sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java/blob/master/microsoft-azure-storage-samples/src/com/microsoft/azure/storage/queue/gettingstarted/QueueBasics.java) in your HttpTrigger Azure Function.***

Step 1: Receive binary data from a queue.

```
   // Setup the cloud storage account.
   CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

   // Create a queue service client
   CloudQueueClient queueClient = account.createCloudQueueClient();

   // Retrieve a reference to a queue
   // Append a random UUID to the end of the queue name so that this

   // sample can be run more than once in quick succession.
   CloudQueue queue = queueClient.getQueueReference("test");

  // Retrieve the first visible message in the queue
    CloudQueueMessage retrieveMessage = queue.retrieveMessage();
```

Step 2: Use `pdfbox` library to process your pdf.

Step 3: Send binary data into a queue.

```
    // Setup the cloud storage account.
    CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

   // Create a queue service client
   CloudQueueClient queueClient = account.createCloudQueueClient();

   // Retrieve a reference to a queue
   // Append a random UUID to the end of the queue name so that this

   // sample can be run more than once in quick succession.
   CloudQueue queue = queueClient.getQueueReference("test");

   // Create messages and add it to the queue
   CloudQueueMessage message1 = new CloudQueueMessage("your pdf data");
                queue.addMessage(message1);
```

***Configure input and output of your HttpTrigger Azure Function.***

Of course,Azure Function supports `zero` or `optional` arguments.

Step 4:You have two methods about configuring `input` and `output` arguments:

**1.Annotations**

```
public class Function {
    public String echo(@HttpTrigger(name = "req", methods = {"post"},  authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS) 
        String req, ExecutionContext context) {
        return String.format(req);
    }
}
```

**2.function.json**

```
{
  "scriptFile": "azure-functions-example.jar",
  "entryPoint": "com.example.MyClass.echo",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "name": "req",
      "direction": "in",
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "methods": [ "post" ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "name": "$return",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

You could get details from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-java).

Hope it helps you.